# Create BMP header in C (can't limit 2 byte fields)

Tags: c, bmp

I'm doing it based on:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

I want to create a BMP image from scratch in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct HEADER {
    short FileType;
    int FileSize;
    short R1;
    short R2;
    int dOffset;
} tp_header;

int main () {
    FILE *image;

    image = fopen("test.bmp", "w");

    tp_header bHeader;

    bHeader.FileType = 0x4D42;
    bHeader.FileSize = 70;
    bHeader.R1 = 0;
    bHeader.R2 = 0;
    bHeader.dOffset = 54;

    fwrite(&bHeader, sizeof(struct HEADER), 1, image);

    return 0;
}
```

I should be getting at output file:

```
42 4D 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
```

But instead i get:

```
42 4D 40 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
```

First of it should contain only 14 bytes. That "40 00" ruins it all. Is that the propper way of setting the header in C? How else can i limit the size in bytes outputed?

Comment: Compilers generally put padding between structure fields. You can't write the whole structure to a file and expect it to just write the fields directly. If you print sizeof(struct HEADER) you'll see that it's longer than the size of each respective field combined. You should also use width-fixed types, like uint32_t and uint16_t instead of int and short.

Comment: I'm now using width-fixed types. If i can't just write the whole structure of a file and expect it to write EXACTLY what i told the computer to, what is the use of programming in writing files?? Seriously, BMP images have a fixed structure, witch i researched about and got how it works, but my compiler shoves undesired data to my file, no longer making it fit the BMP structure and protocol. A file ruined by 4 bytes added for padding...

Comment: Not a duplicate, as writing is not like reading.

Comment: @RFiischer Recall that when BMP file was defined, many PCs used software with 16-bit `int`s.  Think of that when you create a successful  structure using 32-bit fields and later, some future programmer is stuck with 64-bit alignment.

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` might include *padding* bytes between the fields to align the next field to certain address offsets. The values of these padding bytes are indetermined. A typical layout might look like:

```
struct {
    uint8_t field1;
    uint8_t <padding>
    uint8_t <padding>
    uint8_t <padding>
    uint32_t field2;
    uint16_t field3;
    uint8_t <padding>
    uint8_t <padding>
};
```

`<padding>` is just added by the compile; it is not accessible by your program. **This is just an example**. Actual padding may differ and is defined by the ABI for your architecture (CPU/OS/toolchain).

Also, the order in which the bytes of a larger type are stored in memory (*endianess*) depends on the architecture. However, as the file requires a specific endianess, this might also have to be fixed.

Some - **but not all** - compilers alow to specify a `struct` to be `packed` (avoid padding), that still does not help with the endianess-problem.

Best is to serialize the struct properly by shifts and store to an `uint8_t`-array:

```
#include <stdint.h>

/** Write an uint16_t to a buffer.
 *
 *  \returns The next position in the buffer for chaining.
 */
inline uint8_t *writeUInt16(uint8_t *bp, value)
{
    *bp++ = (uint8_t)value;
    *bp++ = (uint8_t)(value >> 8);
    return bp;
}

// similar to writeUInt16(), but for uint32_t.
... writeUInt32( ... )
    ...

int main(void)
{
    ...

    uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], *bptr;

    bptr = buffer;
    bptr = writeUInt16(bptr, 0x4D42U);    // FileType
    bptr = writeUInt32(bptr, 70U);        // FileSize
    ...

}
```

That will fill `buffer` with the header fields. `BUFFER_SIZE` has to be set according to the header you want to create. Once all fields are stored, write `buffer` to the file.

Declaring the functions `inline` hints a good compiler to create almost optimal code for constants.

Note also, that the sizes of `short`, etc. are not fixed. Use `stdint.h` types is you need types of defined size.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution, but i understood what the problem is though.

Comment: @RFiischer: Is there anything particular you do not understand? Maybe I can enhance my answer.

Comment: I think it's the lack of my knowledge that is the problem. What is "buffer" for an example? I don't expect an answer. What is bothering me now is that when the compiler writes to the file anything that contains "10" or "0A" it writes down "0D 0A".

Comment: `buffer` is an array of `uint8_t`. As you write, you apparently pass a _string literal_, where you should pass an integer (variable or literal). The `writeUInt...` functions just take the corresponding integer types (of well defined width) and put them byte-wise into the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your struct is aligned. You ought to write it like

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct HEADER {
    short FileType;
    int FileSize;
    short R1;
    short R2;
    int dOffset;
} tp_header;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Just for you to know — the compiler for optimizing reasons by default would lay it out like:

```
typedef struct HEADER {
    short FileType;
    char empty1; //inserted by compiler
    char empty2; //inserted by compiler
    int FileSize;
    short R1;
    short R2;
    int dOffset;
} tp_header;
```

But you actually made also another error: `sizeof(int) ≥ 4 bytes`. I.e. depending on a platform integer could be 8 bytes. It is important, in such a cases you have to use types like [`int32_t` from `cstdint`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)